# How to skip iterations of a for-in loop (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, swift3, for-in-loop

Is it possible to skip iterations of a for-in loop in Swift 3?

I want to do something like this:

```
for index in 0..<100 {
    if someCondition(index) {
        index = index + 3 //Skip iterations here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple while loop will do

```
var index = 0

while (index < 100) {
    if someCondition(index) {
        index += 3 //Skip 3 iterations here
    } else {
        index += 1
        // anything here will not run if someCondition(index) is true
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work perfectly. The while-loop seems to be the better choice for this situation.

Comment: `while (index < 100) { index += someCondition(index) ? 3 : 1 }`

Comment: Wow - this saved me an hour of thinking... So obvious!

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way is using `continue` within the if condition

```
       for index in 1...100
       {
            if index == 5
            {
               continue
            }
        print(index)//1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10
        }
```

**Or**

```
for index in 1...10 where index%2 == 0
{
  print(index)//2 4 6 8 10
}
```

Comment: by far the normal approach.

Comment: it's normal  :).

Comment: This does not solve the problem, since the desired outcome is to jump the index 3 places.

Answer (score 1):

Continue-statement will only skip once, which is not what was asked for.

A while-loop will work, but if you prefer not to use one:

```
var skipToIndex = 0

for index in 0...100 {

    if index < skipToIndex {
        continue
    }

    if someCondition {
        skipToIndex = index + 3 //Skip three iterations
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be it a .forEach for for-in, you have allways a reference to the current evaluated item. So you can decide on a per item base if you want to continue the iteration.

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

numbers.forEach {
    guard $0 != 3 else { return }
    print($0)
}
```

If your question meant how to stop then have a look on 'break'. If the actual question is about stop when found a specific item, then have a look on .filter.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.