# Swift Break loop for if statement true

Tags: swift

This is basically code asking.

```
for obj in objList {

    if otherObjList.contains(where: { $0.localString == obj.localString}) {
       //if this statement true, I wanna break this statement and 
       //continue loop on the above list (objList)
     } 

}
```

I had try, if the statement true, it's still try to complete loop on otherObjList. By the way, I wanna break this when statement true and continue loop on for objList.

Comment: Use `break` when you found object. @rmaddy i think it is `break`

Comment: @rmaddy - Don't you mean `break`?

Comment: Yes I wanna break that statement and continue loop objList. @TedHopp

Comment: @TedHopp break will exit the loop

Comment: @rmaddy sorry if i am wrong but;  it's still try to complete loop on otherObjList. By the way, I wanna **break** this when statement true and continue loop on for objList.

Comment: maddy and Prashant  using continue and break cannot use even compile cuz it's error.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yeah, I see. I read OP's title but didn't pay enough attention to the comment.

Comment: OtherObjList.contains meant loop contain with condition. not normal statement

Comment: @LeangSocheat You are asking is **first** rather than  **contains** ? it will break loop of otherObjList when it will get object

Comment: Yes. it's something that I want. :D @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: @LeangSocheat https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing parenthesis in the call to `contains()`. Perhaps that's the source of the compiler error?

Comment: Yes, I am not copy from my code, just typing direct in stackoverflow. hehe.. sorry. @TedHopp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41009715/7250862

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be looking for `continue`.

Here's a simple example of the difference between `continue` and `break` :

```
// break
// Prints 1,2,3,4,5
for i in 1 ... 10 {
    print(i, terminator: "")
    if i == 5 {
        break
    }
    print(",", terminator: "")
}
print()

// continue
// Prints 1,2,3,4,56,7,8,9,10,
for i in 1 ... 10 {
    print(i, terminator: "")
    if i == 5 {
        continue
    }
    print(",", terminator: "")
}
print()
```

In short `break` leaves the surrounding loop immediately, whilst `continue` aborts the current iteration and continues the loop with the next iteration.

Comment: to make sure that my statement in "loop for" is not normal as your explanation.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you just want this:

```
for obj in objList {

    if otherObjList.contains(where: { $0.localString == obj.localString }) {
        continue
    }

    // Statements here will not be executed for elements of objList
    // that made the above if-condition true. Instead, the for loop
    // will execute from the top with the next element of objList.
}
```

Comment: It works in my test. If you want more help, you need to post the details of the error.